# Is it an issue when X-axis rods are able to slide in their mounting bracket?

Tags: linear-motion, x-axis

While disassembling my printer, I found that the X-axis rods were able to be slide back and forth within their mounting bracket. This seems like it could lead to this axis shifting from vibration alone.

But, it might not matter, I think, because the extruder carriage is tensioned by a belt and it simply uses the rails as a guide to slide across. Even if the rods were to move, it wouldn't take the carriage along with it.

Will the X-axis rods sliding in their mounting bracket have an affect in print quality?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18MTjdL_epm241k0jUMZSBAIKeJ7JFM9R/view?usp=sharing) is a video:

Answer (score 1):

If the x-axis rods only move in the x axis then there’s no problem, but if they aren’t firmly secured in the other axes then there could be issues.  If they’re able to move then presumably they aren’t secured that well.  Given the relatively small forces involved in 3D printing though, you may well be fine.